Stored procedure issue in DB2 Data Studio
I'm developing a stored procedure for DB2 Database but facing the below error in IBM data studio while creating a stored procedure
Error
Error if I include ; at the end :
DB2 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows: ";" is invalid.
Error if I remove ; at the end :
DB2 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows: "<psm_semicolon>" was expected to form a complete scope.
Tried with setting default statement terminator (;) and removing the same . throwing same error in both the cases

Learn how to use the tool! It has online help. Tip, each separate statement inside the stored-procedure (excluding the final END) needs to be terminated by the configured statement terminator. By defaut, that is a semi-colon.
